# Refreshing label in Python

Tags: python, applet

I creating applet in gnome panel. All code is good. But info in panel is static. But need refresh this info in time. 1 secon or 5 second...

Here is part of python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import gobject
import gtk
import pygtk
import gnomeapplet
import time
import urllib2
pygtk.require('2.0')

def applet_factory(applet, iid):   
   label = gtk.Label("Simple text")
   applet.add(label)
   applet.show_all()

print('Factory started')

if __name__ == '__main__':   # testing for execution
   print('Starting factory')
   gnomeapplet.bonobo_factory('OAFIID:SampleApplet_Factory', 
                              gnomeapplet.Applet.__gtype__, 
                              'Sample Applet', '0.1', 
                              applet_factory)
```

I need refresh "simple text" label in time interval. How did that?

Answer (score 0):

What about...:

```
def applet_factory(applet, iid):   
   label = gtk.Label("Simple text")
   applet.add(label)
   applet.show_all()
   return label

thelabel = applet_factory(applet, iid)

def redrawlabel(*args):
    thelabel.queue_draw()
    # process all events
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration(False)
    return True

# call redrawlabel every 5 minutes
gtk.timeout_add(5*60*1000, redrawlabel)
```

If you also need to set the text to something different, `thelabel.set_text('something else')` will do that.

Comment: File "applet/src/applet.py", line 43
    return label
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: The two `return` statements I show in the above code are inside functions, so I don't know what error you made in transcribing my code (since of course I don't know which line is 43 nor what the other 42+ ones around it are -- how could I possibly know since you decide to hide that?).

Comment: @track, there aren't 43 lines in the code you posted, so the error msg you posted (without showing the line it refers to) remains an utter mystery -- and it **should** have been obvious to you that it would (*think*, man!).  Anyway, since `applet_factory` is called internally by `bonobo_factory`, just remove its `return` and indent the rest of the code I gave to make it part of `applet_factory` -- thogh that can't solve your problem in the mysterious line 43, which must be well after this.  Now, if you don't show us traceback and lines 43 &c, that's all we can possibly do to try and help you.

Comment: 43 line is not required, this all script generated "Simple text". U can solve proble with this part?

Comment: If there is no line 43 then I assure you that you will **not** get a syntax error there -- so remove everything beyond what you've shown in your Q and what I've shown in my A and let us know.